# Setup Jackrabbit Oak with transactions

Tags: java, transactions, jackrabbit-oak

I got Jackrabbit Oak running on top of a MongoDB instance. Pretty simple and pretty much straight from the docs (Sprint Boot application):

```
@PostConstruct
public void initRepository() {
    LOG.info("Initializing Oak repository");

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "deprecation" })
    DB db = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017).getDB("tenantX" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    DocumentNodeStore ns = new DocumentMK.Builder().setMongoDB(db).getNodeStore();

    this.repository = new Jcr(new Oak(ns)).createRepository();

}

@Override
public Session getThreadLocalSession() throws RepositoryException {
    Session session = this.repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
    return session;
}
```

Now, where to from here if I want transactions? Simply adding @Transactional to a service method doesn't change anything.

In our previous "old school" Jackrabbit application we used something like

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.jencks.factory.TransactionManagerFactoryBean" />

<bean id="jcrConnectionManager" class="org.jencks.factory.ConnectionManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transaction" value="xa" />
    <property name="poolMinSize" value="1" />
    <property name="poolMaxSize" value="50" />
    <property name="connectionMaxIdleMinutes" value="5" />
    <property name="partitionStrategy" value="by-connector-properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="jcrManagedConnectionFactory"
    class="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory">
    <property name="configFile" value="classpath:repository.xml" />
    <property name="homeDir" value="/repository" />
</bean>

<bean id="repository"
    class="org.springframework.jca.support.LocalConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="managedConnectionFactory" ref="jcrManagedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="connectionManager" ref="jcrConnectionManager" />
</bean>
```

But Oak doesn't ship with a class like JCAManagedConnectionFactory.